# Как сделать запоминание выбора игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня в игре скины(другая картинка в персонажа) и нужно ,чтобы после выхода игрока из игры его выбор сохранялся(когда он вернется в игру у него должен быть выбранный им же скин(не дефолтный)) .
Я изменяю скины этим кодом:

```
public Sprite Sprite1;

GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite1;
```

Comment: конфиг пробывал?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html почитайте о сохранении данных в Юнити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов - сохраняйте имя спрайта (спрайты должны находиться обязательно в каталоге Resources, в корне этого каталога или вложенной папке, н-р, "Sprites"). Затем в коде по имени спрайта (и заранее известному пути) загружаете спрайт и присваиваете его компоненту.

```
var spriteName = "default";

//Загружаем имя спрайта. Метод реализуйте сами
spriteName = GetPlayerSpriteName();

//Загружаем спрайт
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites\\" + spriteName );
```

Comment: можно сохранять айди скина с помощью PlayerPrefs, а при старте игры подгружать спрайт по пути который отвечает айдишнику